# How do I use a boolean operator in a case statement?

Tags: objective-c

I just Don't understand how to use a boolean operator inside a switch statement

```
switch (expression) {
        case > 20:
            statements
            break;
        case < -20:
            statements
            break;
    }
```

**Edit**:
I don't want an If () statement.

Comment: no behavior when `expression == 20`?

Comment: No, only because case statements are easier to read and they are faster than If () statements.  
I don't want any behavior when `expression == 20`.

Comment: They're faster because they're less powerful. You have to compare against fixed values, one at a time. You can't express what you've shown using a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
switch ((expression) > 20) {
        case true:
            statements
            break;
        case false:
        default:
            statements
            break;
    }
```

What.. you want more than 1 boolean in a case?   You could do this

```
int ii = ((expression) > 20) + 2 * ((expression) < -20);
switch (ii) {
        case 1:
            statements
            break;
        case 2:
            statements
            break;
    }
```

This, IMO is pretty bad code, but it is what you asked for...

Just use the if statement, you'll be better off in the long run.

Comment: I'd like to remind that it's mostly the comparison that makes `if` slower than `switch`es, and consequently this won't help your code go faster.

Comment: actually that's not true.  it's the BRANCH that causes the slowdown, not the comparison.  But a switch is still a branch.

Comment: I'm one year late, but in case someone stumbles over this answer, what I meant was that while both `if` and `switch` cause a branch (and this is the slowest part), what makes `if/else if` pairs slower than a `switch` statement is that they perform one comparison per condition. On the other hand, a `switch` is usually implemented using clever tricks that make it possible to avoid comparisons completely, no matter how many `case`s it has.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. Use `if() ... else ...`.

The nearest thing available to what you want uses a GCC extension and is thus non-standard. You can define ranges in case statements instead of just a value:

```
switch(foo)
{
    case 0 ... 20: // matches when foo is inclusively comprised within 0 and 20
         // do cool stuff
         break;
}
```

However, you can't use that to match *anything* under a certain value. It has to be in a precise range. `Switch`es can only be used to replace the comparison operator against a constant, and can't be used for anything more than that.

Comment: Unfortunately, speed comes at the cost of flexibility, and there's no way around using a boolean operator instead a switch. It's faster because the CPU has less work to do on it. If you could use a boolean operator inside a `switch`, there would be no reason `if` statements would be any slower than `switch` statements.

Comment: What happens when I have more than like 5 cases though?

Comment: Well, it's just my rule of the thumb, and I didn't mean to make it look like such an absolute rule. You do whatever you like in that case. I'm going to edit that.

Comment: Then you use the 'else if' statement to handle them. As others have said, 'switch' is for situations with known result values.